# AWS Federation Identity with LDAP

Tags: amazon-web-services, ldap, federated-identity

I managed to integrate logging into EC2 linux and windows based on integration to Simple AD LDAP. 
What I am looking at now, is there possible to authorize users based on AD Groups. Let's imagine we have user John who is in Developers Group. I would like John to be able to login to EC2 instances that has a tag - "Dev". Different user, who might be in Production Group access only servers with "Prod" tag.

Thanks for any suggestions.
Michal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure this using Federated Identities. Here is the blog post from AWS on [Enabling Federation to AWS Using Windows Active Directory](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/enabling-federation-to-aws-using-windows-active-directory-adfs-and-saml-2-0/) or you can also use [AWS SSO](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/what-is.html) to integrate with your windows AD

After that, you can create roles to restrict access by tags using policies.

Comment: I am aware of Federation Identity with LDAP for AWS Console, but wondering if I can combine with logging to EC2 via ssh and IAM Roles.